# Libgdx - Navigating between screens in Android

Tags: android, libgdx

I have a simple structure of three screens: start, menu and game.
When the user is in the game and press the back button, returns to the menu screen, and pressing back again, go to start screen. Like the image below.

[image]

The problem is that is going straight to the start screen when I press the back button on Game Screen. Should go to the menu screen.

Which is the correct way to do that?

Classes:

```
public class GameScreen extends ScreenAdapter implements InputProcessor, Screen, GestureListener
public class MenuScreen extends ScreenAdapter implements InputProcessor
public class StartScreen extends ScreenAdapter implements InputProcessor
```

On both classes:

```
Show(){
Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true);
}
```

On GameScreen Class:

```
 @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {    
        if(keycode == Keys.BACK){
        bb.setScreen(new MenuScreen(bb,game,adsController,actionResolver));
     }
    return false;
 }
```

On Menu Screen Class:

```
render() {
if (Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Keys.BACK)){
    bb.setScreen(new StartScreen(bb,game,adsController,actionResolver));
    }
}
```

Note: The code like below works fine on GameScreen but on MenuScreen or on StartScreeen, when press the back button, nothing happens. Why?

```
@Override
public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {    
    if(keycode == Keys.BACK){
        bb.setScreen(new MenuScreen(bb,game,adsController,actionResolver));
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comments above you are calling

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```

this will not catch the functions implemented from

```
implements InputProcessor
```

Try calling a inputmultiplexer in show(), something like:

```
show()
{
    InputMultiplexer multiplexer = new InputMultiplexer();
    multiplexer.addProcessor(this);
    multiplexer.addProcessor(stage);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(multiplexer);
}
```

Comment: And about the first problem (The problem is that is going straight to the start screen when I press the back button on Game Screen. Should go to the menu screen) any suggestion? Or this way solves both problems?

Comment: try using the onkeyup in stead of key down, i suspect its a fall through kind of problem that it instantaniously calls the start menu because the back button is still down.

Comment: The GameScreen Class works with inputmultiplexer, but de StartScreen and MenuScreen dont, keyUp ou keyDown do nothing. Only Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed on render method works. Any idea?

Comment: then why do you implement InputProcessor? It doesn't sound very useful to catch off screen input, if you want to duplicate behavior maybe create an extendable MyScreen class?

Comment: I forgot the line multiplexer.addProcessor(this) on one class. My fault. Added this line, works fine. And the keyup solved the problem with the back button. Thanks  a lot for your help.

Comment: No problem! Would you mind accepting the answer then?